# Math.random javascripts with php variable

Tags: javascript, php

I would like to use php variable in my javascript. 
This is what I currently have and is working just fine:

```
<?php 
$test = '"test1","test2",test3"';
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
var values = [<?php echo $test; ?>],
valueToUse = values[Math.floor(Math.random() * values.length)];
alert(valueToUse);
</script>
```

However, if I use values that are retrieved from a database, this code will not work. Both variables contain exactly same values and are string type.

Comment: Why don't you just use PHP's `rand()`?

Comment: What  does your JS look like after rendering the PHP code? What JS errors are you getting?

Comment: The snippet is lacking a quotation for `test3` and should result in a syntax error in JavaScript. Also, to help avoid typos like that, consider using `$test = array('test1', 'test2', 'test3');` and `var values = <?php echo json_encode($test); ?>;`. ([How to pass variables and data from PHP to JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740548/how-to-pass-variables-and-data-from-php-to-javascript))

Comment: It's a string because your php variable your giving to it is a string. So your resulting values array will always be [string] at which point your random number generates a number between 0 and 1 then floors it which means except for the very very rare chance you get a 1 it grabs your array at value 0 which is the only value your string.

Comment: U can't use JS with PHP dude

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
$test = 'test1,test2,test3';
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
var values = <?php echo $test; ?>;
values=values.split(",");
valueToUse = values[Math.floor(Math.random() * values.length)];
alert(valueToUse);
</script>
```

Your problem was your test variable was a sting however if you call the JavaScript split function on a  string it easily turns a , separated list into a JavaScript array